# Тире перед частицей

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с отдельными случаями постановки тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Все примеры взяты из Нацкорпуса.

1. Сущ. (им. п.) + оборот с числительным

*Киили – еще одна жертва человеческого невежества и подлости.*

Правильно ли я понимаю, что частица «мешает» ставить тире, только если сказуемое выражено существительным? Об авторской пунктуации (интонационном тире) речь не идет.

2. Инф. + инф.

*Деформировать череп – еще не значит что-то доказать.*

*Предлагать вопросы еще не значит спрашивать.*

*Знать на зубок ещё не значит знать.*

Верно ли, что в этом случае перед связкой (с любой частицей) тире ставится всегда? Если это так, то примеры без тире – проявление воли автора или все же есть коварное «но»?..

Comment: Мне кажется дело не в частице, а в том, что одна - это подлежащее у правой части, как и что-то. Знать на зубок ещё не значит знать. - тут подлежащее "знать на зубок", а сказуемое "не значит знать".  Предлагать вопросы еще не значит спрашивать. - а вот тут можно и тире поставить, в зависимости от интонации. Предлагать вопросы - (это) еще не значит спрашивать.

Comment: Спасибо, заставили задуматься. Для меня разница между последними двумя примерами не очевидна.

Comment: знать на зубок - фразеологизм, он не бьется, предлагать вопросы - можно разбить на отдельные слова и произнести с акцентом какое-то одно из них.

Answer (score 3):

**Тема 1**

**Киили* – еще одна **жертва** человеческого невежества и подлости.*

В данном случае тире ставится по общему правилу: **[Розенталь, п. 1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)**

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа.

***Еще один*** имеет значение **определения**: *добавочный, дополнительный*.

**[Словарь синонимов.](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/42589/%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5)** *добавочный, сверхштатный, лишний, сверхкомплектный, дополнительный, прибавочный.*

**ОДИН**. II. в зн. прил. 4. Определённый (из числа однородных лиц, предметов, явлений). Одна из моих книг потеряна.

**Тема 2**

**Я думаю,** что во всех приведенных примерах используется глагол ***значит***, а не связка ***значит***.

**ЗНАЧИТЬ**, -нсв. 1. что, с инф. или с придат. дополнит. **Иметь какой-л. смысл, означать** (о словах, знаках, жестах и т. п.). Имя Виктор значит победитель. Кивок головы значит согласие. Поднятая вверх рука дрессировщика значила **стоять**. Изумлённый взгляд слушателя значил, что он не согласен. // **Свидетельствовать о чём-л., означать что-л**. Что значат эти радостные возгласы? Если обвинение не доказано, **это не значит**, что обвиняемый не виноват. Узнать, понять, почувствовать, что значит быть отцом (узнать и т. п., что это такое).

Постановка тире определяется расстановкой **логических ударений**.

(1) **Тире ставится**, если нужно выделить ударением первую часть сообщения.

*Деформировать чЕреп – // **еще не значит** что-то доказАть.*

Это законченная мысль.

(2) **Тире не ставится**, если ударением выделена **вторая часть:**

*Предлагать вопросы / **еще не значит** спрАшивать. Знать на зубок / **ещё не значит** знАть.*

Это незаконченная мысль, далее следует продолжение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ!